# Ao entrar no PostAsync nunca obtenho uma resposta

Tags: c#, api, async, async-await, sendgrid

Olá,

Estou tendo um problema com uma utilização de PostAsync que, teoricamente era para estar funcionando normalmente. O código não é de compreensão muito complexa:

`HttpResponseMessage response = await cliente.PostAsync("/v3/mail/send", stringContent);`

antes de chegar neste método ele segue normalmente o código, o que acontece basicamente é que ele 'some' no post e nunca dá um retorno ao response.
Um ponto chave que está me confundindo é que isso funciona, realizando corretamente o trabalho da API chamada e retornando instantaneamente o que se é esperado:

`HttpResponseMessage response = cliente.PostAsync("/v3/mail/send", stringContent).Result;`

Mas durante as pesquisas entendi como pode ser perigoso e errado usar o PostAsync assim.

Também tentei a utilização do `ConfigureAwait(false)` porém, também sem sucesso. Desde já agradeço, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda

Comment: Não adicione no titulo palavras para se referir ao estado da pergunta, como: `Resolvido`, `Fechado`, `Concluído`, `Urgente`, `Ajuda`, `Socorro`. Titulos devem ser claros e ao mesmo tempo breves e objetivos, outras perguntas que pode notar que contenham exatamente os seguintes termos `[fechada]` ou `[pendente]`, são textos adicionados pelo sistema, e não fazem parte do titulo real, são apenas indicativos automáticos para tornar mais intuivo o estado real da pergunta sobre um motivo de fechamento defindo em [O que significa se uma pergunta está "fechada" ou "pendente"?](/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ninguém chegou a responder mas cheguei à uma resposta que pode ajudar alguém futuramente então pretendo fechar a questão e deixar a resposta que me serviu aqui:

Esse método `async Task<T> EnviarEmail` que contém o `PostAsync` É chamado por um método que também é `async Task<T>`, que por sua vez era chamado através de `Task<>.Result` em uma Action Síncrona. Basicamente o que resolveu o problema foi deixar essa Action assim: `async Task<ActionResult>` e antes da chamada do método também usar do `await`.